# To pointer or not to pointer? Or is this a pointer at all?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management, garbage-collection

Alright, it's been a long time since I've worked with pointers. And now I've been writing .NET code for more than a decade so I haven't had to deal with them. In fact, in .NET it's really nice because if it's not a value type then it's clearly a reference type, or by definition a pointer.

So, in .NET when I declare a `string` it's most certainly a pointer underlying because it's a reference type:

```
string s = "Hello Mike!";
```

However, it appears that in Objective-C I can declare a string two different ways:

```
NSString* s = "Hello Mike!";
NSString s = "Hello Mike!";
```

Now, if I'm understanding this correctly the first declaration is very similar to the underlying declaration of a string in .NET, a pointer. But what exactly is the second?

Now bear in mind I may be way off base here because I'm just starting to dig into Objective-C, so please excuse my ignorance!

Comment: Have you tried to actually compile both your `NSString` examples.  Both of them are incorrect and cause warnings and errors for me.  The correct syntax would be `NSString *s = @"Hello Mike!";`

Comment: @mttrb, not really, I'm more at a conceptual level. If you know the correct syntax please feel free to edit the question and accept my apologies. I've seen it written so many ways when studying that it didn't appear to matter honestly.

Comment: Neither of those is valid Objective-C, if you've seen it written that way elsewhere then they are wrong.

Comment: @mttrb, that aside. Can you tell me the difference between declaring `NSString` as a pointer and not declaring `NSString` as a pointer? Or is it not really possible to declare `NSString` as a pointer and what I've seen is just wrong?

Comment: The variable must be a pointer. The correct syntax for an Objective-C `NSString` is `@"Hello Mike!`.  Note the leading `@`.

Comment: @mttrb, and so what does the `@` signify? The creation of a memory address with that value in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from REALbasic to Objective-C was similar for me: they both use pointers as references to object instances, but in REALbasic that fact is implicit, whereas Objective-C is C and therefore must make it explicit. That fact, however, is really just an accident of notation. The implications, for things like assignment and comparison, are similar.

You might be helped by reading the relevant entry from my book on this topic:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_an_instance_reference_is_a_pointer

(The fact that you don't seem to understand yet how to form an NSString literal (it starts with an at-sign, e.g. `@"hello"`, is secondary.)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you friend, I will be spending time reading through this book!

Comment: If I buy this book, how much different is iOS 6 development? I'm not building very complex apps, so I'm hoping that investing in this book will be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your `NSString` declarations should actually compile.  The first should tell you that it's an incompatible assignment because your assigning a C string pointer as if it were an object address.  The second should tell you that you can't actually declare an object, only a pointer to an object.  The correct syntax is:

```
NSString* s = @"Hello Mike!";
```

In this case, `s` is a pointer variable which contains the address of a string object, having the "Hello Mike!" value.

Comment: So, is this true? Just like .NET, unless it's a value type like `int`, everything in Objective-C must be declared as a pointer?

Comment: No idea about .NET but Objective-C is a superset of C.  All of the C stuff is available to be referenced directly (int, char, float...), but the object layer on top of it needs dynamic allocation, therefore heap storage, therefore pointers.